# How to avoid page refreshing when i click the back button

Tags: session, struts2, refresh, interceptor

Am using struts2 to create login and logout functionality, when user login i will create the session for him,by using interceptor i will filter all users if they are in session or not if the session not created i will redirect the page to login........my problem is once i done logout that will redirect to the login page but when user click browser back button the page will get refreshed and again that will login ,,,,,,could anybody help me out from this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: could anyone help me how to set the cookie in struts 2 and check for each user logout

Answer (score 0):

When you click "<-" button on browser the browser renders the page from its cache. So server does not know if you have click back button. In your case *when user clicks back button, page is loaded from cache but it does not mean that session is again created for that user as logged in*. When user will click on any authorized link on that page, your server side code will check that user has no valid session and login page will be returned.
**Solution:** However if you do not want user to get cached page then you can load a script say checkLogin.js for every page in your site. This script should be executed on load event of the pages. When user logs out, set a variable in cookie indicating that user has logged out. When user clicks back button then that script will be executed. That script will check, using the mentioned cookie variable, if user has logged out. If user had logged out then redirect to login page using javascript.

Comment: thank u for your valuable time can u plz explain me how to do that if u don't mind

Comment: Do you want whole code or something specific like accessing cookie or ... ?

Comment: i am very new to this struts2 can u plz post me that whole code thank u

Comment: I do not know struts. I am .net guy. But your problem is not dependent on particular technology. You need to search how to set cookie in structs and then search how to access cookie using javascript. I am sure you will find it. I have explained how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that refreshing i have redirect my page to menu after loginsuccess not forward i have escaped from that ghost problem
use like this in ur struts.xml

```
<result name= success" type="redirect">Menu.jsp</result>
```

thanks for all